# eBay API returns 'IAF Token supplied is invalid' error

Tags: php, ebay-api

I want to use eBay API for retrieving all feedback of seller. I already have prepared the APPID, CERTID, DEVID, in both environments (sandbox, production). I use API EXplorer for test.

I already encoded to base 64 appid:certid and got oauth application token by this tutorial https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html#The
. So when I want to get feedback I specify only token, Trading API, GetFeedback API call, leaving USERID field empty to receive only feedback to my sells and now this strange error:

```
Invalid IAF token.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending it via headers, I used

```
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>TOKEN HERE</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
```

In your respective XML call and it worked!